# Combine and show data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with respective colums

EDIT: I need data from both the tables. If there are no event for a timestamp in Table1, I need the record in the display. But if there are events corresponding to TimeStamp from Table2 (the startTime in the Query)

```
Table1:                     
Sensor ID   TimeStamp   Payload1    Payload2            

Table2:                     
Sensor ID   TimeStamp   EventName   EventValue  State
```

And then have a result rest which combines the two tables:

```
Result:                     
Sensor ID   TimeStamp   Payload1    Payload2    EventName   EventValue  State
```

I am trying to figure out a SQL which will give me the right result set.

Currently I get duplicate rows when I try. the result set will look something like:

```
Sensor ID   TimeStamp               Payload1    Payload2    EventName   EventValue  State
2           17/06/2019 11:21:47 AM  205.8   237.9   NULL    NULL    NULL
2           17/06/2019 11:21:49 AM  205.8   244.1   NULL    NULL    NULL
2           17/06/2019 11:21:51 AM  205.8   235.8   NULL    NULL    NULL
2           17/06/2019 11:21:51 AM  NULL    NULL    Event1  205.8   Critical
```

What I am trying to get is something like this:

```
Sensor ID   TimeStamp               Payload1    Payload2    EventName   EventValue  State
2           17/06/2019 11:21:47 AM  205.8       237.9       NULL        NULL    NULL
2           17/06/2019 11:21:49 AM  205.8       244.1       NULL        NULL    NULL
2           17/06/2019 11:21:51 AM  205.8       235.8       Event1      205.8   Critical
```

The query which I use looks something like this

```
SELECT SensorID,
           [TimeStamp],
           Payload1 AS Payload1,
           Payload2 AS Payload2,
           INTO #TempTable1
    FROM Feed.data
    WHERE AssetId = 1
          AND [TimeStamp] > GETDATE() - 0.05
         ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC;

    SELECT E.SensorID,
           E.StartTime AS [TimeStamp],
           ET.Name AS EventName,
           E.EventValue,
           E.State
    INTO #TempTable2
    FROM [Event] E
        JOIN [EventType] ET
            ON E.EventTypeId = ET.Id
    WHERE E.SensorID = 1
          AND ET.Id IN ( 1, 2 )
          AND StartTime > GETDATE() - 0.05
    --AND  E.Severity != 'Normal' 
    ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC;

    SELECT CASE
               WHEN T1.SensorID IS NOT NULL THEN
                   T1.SensorID
               ELSE
                   T2.SensorID
           END AS AssetId,
           CASE
               WHEN [TimeStamp] IS NOT NULL THEN
                   TimeStamp
               ELSE
                   EventTimeStamp
           END AS TimeStamp,
           Payload1,
           Payload2,
           T2.EventName,
           T2.EventValue,
           T2.State
    FROM #TempTable1 T1
        FULL OUTER JOIN #TempTable2 T2
            ON T1.TimeStamp = T2.EventTimeStamp
               AND T1.SensorID = T2.SensorID
    ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC;

    --Select * from #TempTable1 
    --Select * from #TempTable2 

    DROP TABLE #TempTable1;
    DROP TABLE #TempTable2;
```

Comment: Have you tried inner join instead of full outer join?

Comment: Post sample data, I think query can be simplified.

Comment: An Inner Join would make more sense here, post DDL for the sample data so we could help with the query

Comment: simply just use left join instead of full outer join

Comment: Where you displaying data? If you have some client application, then most of the job can be done there, instead of abusing sql server ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want,

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.[SensorID],t2.[SensorID]) AS [AssetId]
        ,ISNULL(t1.[TimeStamp],t2.[TimeStamp]) AS [EventTimeStamp]
        ,t1.[Payload1]
        ,t1.[Payload2]
        ,t2.[EventName]
        ,t2.[EventValue]
        ,t2.[State]
FROM Feed.data t1
OUTER APPLY (                       -- CROSS APPLY in case you need matching records alone
SELECT E.[SensorID]
        ,E.[StartTime] AS [TimeStamp]
        ,ET.[Name] AS EventName
        ,E.[EventValue]
        ,E.[State]
FROM [Event] E
    JOIN [EventType] ET
        ON E.[EventTypeId] = ET.[Id]
WHERE E.[SensorID] = 1
        AND ET.[Id] IN ( 1, 2 )
        AND E.[StartTime] > GETDATE() - 0.05
        AND t1.[TimeStamp] = E.[StartTime]
        AND t1.[SensorID] = E.[SensorID] ) t2
WHERE t1.[AssetId] = 1
    AND t1.[TimeStamp] > GETDATE() - 0.05

ORDER BY ISNULL(t1.[TimeStamp],t2.[TimeStamp]) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use union all, group by timestamp.

## code:

```
select Sensor ID   TimeStamp   Payload1    Payload2  
from Table1
Group by Sensor ID, TimeStamp 
Union all
select Sensor ID   TimeStamp   EventName   EventValue  State 
from Table 2
Group by   Sensor ID   TimeStamp
```

## note :

1. you can use union also, Union will delete duplicate rows.
2. Union all will not delete duplicate rows.

--> use operators(union or union all) according to the requirements.

Comment: This SQL would not work, and if somehow it did work it would not achieve the requirements listed.  In a union each part needs to return the same number of columns with the same data types in the same order. The group bys would do nothing more than order each part of the union before doing the union, and without a join the related data would not be joined on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joining both tables and then select required columns. INNER JOIN will return a record with Sensor ID that available in both tables. But if you wants to see records if at least available in table1, just replace the INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT 
[Sensor ID],TimeStamp,
Payload1,Payload2,
EventName,EventValue,State
FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.[Sensor ID] = B.[Sensor ID]
-- Above is the basic query. You can now 
-- add filtering with the query as per your requirement as-
WHERE A.[TimeStamp] > GETDATE() - 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple union query, and group by to combine the two sets of data. This will work regardless of which table the data is, assuming there is not a match in the other table.

```
select SensorID, [Timestamp],
    max(PayLoad1) PayLoad1,
    max(PayLoad2) PayLoad2,
    max(EventName) EventName,
    max(EventValue) EventValue,
    max([State]) [State]
from (  
    select SensorID, [TimeStamp], PayLoad1, PayLoad2, 
        null EventName, null EventValue, null [State] 
    from table1
    union
    select SensorID, [TimeStamp], null PayLoad1, null PayLoad2, 
        EventName, EventValue, [State] 
    from table2
    ) q
group by SensorID, [Timestamp]
```